# nested for loops making square

Tags: java, nested-loops

I wanna make a square with numbers.Something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6
```

And i wrote a peace of code:

```
int a=input.nextInt();
for(int i=1; i<=a; i++){
    for (int k=1;k<=a;k++){
        int c=k+1;
        int g=k+2;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(k+" ");
        System.out.print(c+" ");
        System.out.print(g+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

the result is:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6 

1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6
```

So, where is the mistake?

Comment: As peaceful as your code is, the expected result matches the result you gave, so there's nothing to help you with.

Comment: Your output is matching your expectation!

Comment: `So, where is the mistake?` Missing in action! It does what you said.

Comment: Well, that's not a square for a start. Also I can't reproduce your output with the code you gave. What's the value for `a`? It defines how many "squares" the program writes, but with `a=2` the output is `1 2 3 
2 3 4 

1 2 3 
2 3 4` .

Comment: @Djon Clearly his input doesn't match his output. He wants one and got two squares.

Comment: @Narmer I tested the code with different values for `a` and it obviously isn't correct in any way, `c` and `g` initialized with +1 and +2 are a bad sign.

Comment: @Djon Yep, I'm totally with you that the code is broken. You should have tested that before commenting tough to understand what the OP meant with "bad result". Judging from comments, you're not alone.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing a full square in the second loop. The first one is producing multiple squares.

Try this code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //      int a=input.nextInt();
      int a = 4;

      for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
         for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
            System.out.print(i + k);
            System.out.print(" ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, Tobias! This is the answert , who i search :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove your first loop it will print only one square.

```
int a=input.nextInt();
//for(int i=1; i<=a; i++){  comment this one
  for (int k=1;k<=a;k++){
    int c=k+1;
    int g=k+2;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(k+" ");
    System.out.print(c+" ");
    System.out.print(g+" ");
 }
System.out.println();
//} and this
```

and square will only be printed if you give input as 3.

```
1 2 3 
2 3 4 
3 4 5
```

for your square

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

int a=3;
//for(int i=1; i<=a; i++){
    for (int k=1;k<=a;k++){
    int c=k+1;
    int g=k+2;
    int e=k+3;//added
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(k+" ");
    System.out.print(c+" ");
    System.out.print(g+" ");
     System.out.print(e+" ");//added
    }
System.out.println();
//}
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a single loop will do just fine in your case.

Considering you are taking number of rows as input

your loop should run from i=1 to i<=a.

you don't need to take another loop just print i,i+1,i+2,i+3 inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public static void main(String[] args) {          
          int a = 4;
          for (int i = 1; i <= a-1; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                System.out.print(i + j);
                System.out.print(" ");
             }
             System.out.println();
          }
       }
```

Comment: Thank u Sandeep. This is the answered i was looking for :)